# Looking for title of short story with Transhuman that eat dog from Hartwell Best SF collection

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic

There a 3 characters, each a member of a trio of surveyors.  They are vaguely military, transhuman, policing some hinterland zone of future earth in which bio organic life is rare.  They come across an organic dog living in the wild. One of the team adopts the dog.  Eventually they become bored with the dog and eat it on a beach. This appeared in Hartwell Best of SF collection after 2000, probably in the last 12-15 years.

Answer (score 7):

This is ["The People of Sand and Slag"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_People_of_Sand_and_Slag) (2004) by Paolo Bacigalupi. A brief summary from Wikipedia:

> The story follows three genetically modified humans who work as guards for a large mining conglomeration in a far future Montana. It begins with the three of them being called out to track down an intruder on their employer's property. When they finally corner it they realize it is nothing more than a dog. Fascinated by the fact that it could still survive in their day and age they decide to keep it as a pet, and then constantly struggle to keep it fed, clean, healthy and alive.